# A Question Related to the Divergence Test for Series

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, soft-question

Suppose $\lbrace x_i\rbrace$ is a sequence of real numbers. 
If $\lim x_i=0$ then for every $\varepsilon>0$ there exists an $N$ such that $$n\ge N\Rightarrow \vert x_n\vert<\varepsilon\qquad(*)$$

Further, if $\sum_{i=0}^\infty \vert x_i\vert<\infty$, then for every $\varepsilon>0$ there is an $N$ such that $$n\ge N\Rightarrow \sum_{i=n}^\infty \vert x_i \vert<\varepsilon$$

Question: From the latter inequality, $(*)$ holds. Since summability is a stronger condition than $\lim x_i=0$, shouldn't there be a condition on the terms $\vert x_i \vert$ that is stronger than $(*)$.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question - is not the condition $\sum_{i=n}^\infty \vert x_i \vert<\varepsilon$ the same as the condition that the $\vert x_i \vert$ are summable?

Comment: @alex.jordan, yes I replaced $i$ with $n$. Yes, but all I can conclude from summability about the terms $x_i$ is (*). Since summability is stronger than $\lim x_i =0$ I want to know if I can make a stronger conclusion on the terms $x_i$ for large $i$ when summability holds.

Comment: You can say things like "the $\left|x_i\right|$ converge to $0$ _faster_ than $\frac{1}{i}$ or $\frac{1}{i\ln(i)}$, etc." But what you usually want to stress is that the terms are converging to $0$ fast enough for them to be summable, and there is no real borderline condition for that; so just saying that they are summable may be what you are after.

Comment: You could say for example that it is not the case that there is a positive number $c$ for which $x_i>c/n$ for all sufficiently large $n$. This is stronger than that $x_i \to 0$, for example consider $x_i=1/\sqrt{i}.$

Comment: @alex.jordan, I wish to formalize that. Or, at least, I wish that it is possible to do so, but I agree that it is borderline :)

Comment: @coffeemath is $\sum \frac{1}{i}$ the smallest/slowest divergent series?

Comment: @TheSubstitute I think there are smaller ones like $\sum \frac{1}{k \ln k}.$

Comment: Or $\sum\frac{1}{i\ln(i)\ln(\ln(i))\cdots\ln^{\circ k}(i)}$. And I'm sure that examples can be found that converge even faster without summing. It's going to be like finding the max in $(0,1)$. You also can't approach this from the other side though for similar reasons. You are searching for "$1$" in $(0,1)\cup(1,2)$, and I don't think it can be found.